# Why can anonymous users access private files using the system URL?

Tags: files

I have a private organic group with a private organic groups post. I have properly setup my private files system. If an image is uploaded to the private folder an anonymous user can still access it with the following URL:

```
/system/files/private/assets/image.jpg
```

However they are given a Forbidden: You don't have permission to access this on this server when access the URL this way:

```
/sites/default/files/private/assets/image.jpg
```

My guess is that Drupal is not doing it's job in the first instance; as I haven't set up private file system properly and Apache is doing it's job in the second URL due to the htaccess file in there.

Any pointers?

Comment: Can't comment as to why, but [this module](https://drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission) should help solve the problem

Comment: I'll give that module a go and see what we can do, however, my understanding is that whatever permissions are protecting the node should be protecting the files/images tied to that node. I know the og permissions are working as an anonymous user cannot view the node directly, but they can access the files/images directly that are attached to that node (even though they are in the private folder).

Comment: Are the files/images attached via a field?

Comment: Looking at [`file_file_download()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_file_download/7), access to files attached to fields (not images, those are handled separately) is based on an invocation of [`hook_file_download_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21file%21file.api.php/function/hook_file_download_access/7). No core modules implement that hook so I get the impression it's left to the developer to implement. I might be wrong, that does seem a bit suspicious. But as far as I can tell from the code it's right

Comment: I have attached one to an image field and the second is in the body field. Both are in the same private folder. I have given that module a go and interestingly enough, just enabling the module makes Drupal behave as expected. I haven't even defined any directories to protect through the module yet. Also, I don't think this module will do it because it is based on site permissions, not og group permissions.

Comment: Yeah the more I think about it, the more that module is the "missing part" of the core private file system. When I first saw this question I went straight to the perms page to look for the file download permission (that made the most sense) and was a bit surprised not to find it. The reason that module makes things work is that core/organic groups doesn't actually provide _any_ access checks for private files; so there's nothing to override. Again, that's unless I'm missing something!

Comment: I have just tried using 2 other access control modules and I can replicate the same behaviour and indeed the Private files download permission module fixes it. I tested https://drupal.org/project/content_access and https://drupal.org/project/node_view_permissions

Comment: It's interesting that just enabling the module fixes the issue without even defining any directories to protect in it's setting at /admin/config/media/private-files-download-permission. IMHO there's something in this module that should be converted to a core patch to make Drupal behave as expected when using a private files setup. It seems that Drupal core just creates the private files folder and adds an htaccess file, without actually doing any access checks itself afterwards.

Comment: I think that makes sense - for the best security it would probably be based on a whitelist over the entire private file system by default. But I'm not sure, too lazy to read the code right now - at least it works! The Drupal-ignorance thing doesn't make sense IMO though, that feels like it should be built in. Just so happens every time I've implemented private files I've always implemented the download hooks anyway because the project called for it. I'd never noticed the core behaviour

Comment: It's kind of scary to think that this could actually be a huge security issue. e.g. Someone using the backup and migrate module will be storing their backups in a private folder and a user could potentially poke for the folder using the system url method rather than the relative path to the file. *shudders*

Comment: That is scary. So scary it makes me think I must have missed something, or this would at least be a well-known issue. If I uncover anything else I'll put an answer in

Comment: Holy hell. I just tested with the private folder outside of the site root (inaccessible directly by your web server) e.g. ../private and I can access it using the system URL too. This is on a vanilla install of drupal. All I did was change the default article content type image field to use the private file system. I could access the file directly using the system url. And once again, just enabling that private files download permissions module fixes it immediately.

Comment: Sure enough, this is a core issue but is only fixed for D8 with the inclusion of file entity on core; nothing for D7 though and I gues is left to each access control module in contrib to implement their own checks. https://drupal.org/node/1227706

Answer (score 1):

`/sites/default/files/private/assets/image.jpg` will never work because of an .htaccess directive prohibiting direct access to that directory.

Beyond that, this strikes me as an issue with OG.  I'd try executing a `module_implements('file_download')` and have a look at what modules might be interacting with determining if a given file is accessible.

Comment: So this is indeed an issue with OG, however there is some funky stuff going on in Core as noted in my conversation with @Clive above. It seems that my expectations of core is that it should protect access to the files directly unless they are being view through the node. It also appears to be hit and miss with other access control modules, whether or not they are also implementing a file access function. For the specific issue for OG, see https://drupal.org/node/985656